# How can I update a file using SAXParser in Java

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

I am using SAX parser to read data from the xml. Now I want to modify the data using SAX parser. how can I do that?

My XML file is,

```
<ProductCatalog>
    <item id="w1" type="SmartWatches">
        <name>Apple Watch</name>
        <price>400</price>
        <image>abc.jpg</image>
        <manufacturer>Apple</manufacturer>
        <condition>New</condition>
        <discount>10</discount>
        <accessories>
            <accessory>charger</accessory>
            <accessory>belt</accessory>
        </accessories>
    </item>

    <item id="w2" type="SmartWatches">
        <name>Apple Watch</name>
        <price>400</price>
        <image>abc.jpg</image>
        <manufacturer>Apple</manufacturer>
        <condition>New</condition>
        <discount>10</discount>
        <accessories>
            <accessory>charger</accessory>
            <accessory>belt</accessory>
        </accessories>
    </item>
</ProductCatalog>
```

And also this is my implementation of SAX parser in java.

```
public class UserHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    private Item item;
    private String value;
    private String filePath;
    private Map<String, Item> map = new HashMap<String, Item>();

    UserHandler(String filePath) {
        this.filePath = filePath;
        parseDocument();
        printValue();
    }

    private void printValue() {
        Set keys = map.keySet();
        for (Iterator i = keys.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            String key = (String) i.next();
            System.out.println("Key : " + key);

            Item itemDemo = map.get(key);
            System.out.println("Name : " + itemDemo.getName());
            System.out.println("Price : " + itemDemo.getPrice());
            System.out.println("Image : " + itemDemo.getImage());
            System.out.println("Manufacturer : " + itemDemo.getManufacturer());
            System.out.println("Condition : " + itemDemo.getCondition());
            System.out.println("Discount : " + itemDemo.getDiscount());
            System.out.println("Accessories : " + itemDemo.getAccessories().toString());
        }
    }

    private void parseDocument() {
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
            parser.parse(filePath, this);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            System.out.println("ParserConfig error");
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            System.out.println("SAXException : xml not well formed");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
            item = new Item();
            item.setId(attributes.getValue("id"));
            item.setType(attributes.getValue("type"));
        }
    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        if (qName.equals("item")) {
            map.put(item.getId(), item);
            return;
        }
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
            item.setName(value);
            return;
        }
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("price")) {
            item.setPrice(value);
            return;
        }
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("image")) {
            item.setImage(value);
            return;
        }
        if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("manufacturer")){
            item.setManufacturer(value);
            return;
        }
        if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("condition")){
            item.setCondition(value);
            return;
        }
        if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("discount")){
            item.setDiscount(value);
            return;
        }
        if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("accessory")){
            item.getAccessories().add(value);
            return;
        }
    }

    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        value = new String(ch, start, length);
    }
}
```

How can I modify a particular attribute in XML file? The changes should be replicated in file also. I cannot use DOM parser.

Comment: SAX Parser just parses an XML file and generates events. However, you can create a new file and write the modified XML elements as you receive the SAX events.

Comment: Usually, SAX is used for searching and reading. but not for the modification.

Comment: is SAX a requirement because of the file sizes?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you seem to be doing some XML-object binding manually through a SAX parser. It would make a lot more sense to use [JAXB, which takes care of this for you](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/). Since you already have an `Item` class with the necessary properties (getters/setters), it would probably take a minimum of JAXB annotations and a `ProductCatalog` class (with a list of Items) to make it possible to fully *unmarshal* XML to objects, and *marshal* objects to XML.

Depending on how you want to alter things, there's a couple of approaches possible. If you want to alter the content of the XML, but not do things like change the names of elements or attributes, or change namespaces, then using the above mentioned JAXB to turn the XML into Java objects, manipulate those and turn them back into XML would suffice. The code for doing the JAXB marshalling/unmarshalling is minimal, and all the rest would be handling POJOs through familiar Java code.

If you want to drastically alter the structure of your XML, or do things like rename elements/attributes, then you might wish to look into [XSLT, which is an XML-based transformation language](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt). XSLT processing in Java is fast and efficient. It takes a bit of getting used to, but with the correct mindset XSLT becomes a very powerful tool in manipulating XML.

Both the JAXB and XML transformation APIs have been part of the Java SE API for quite a long time now, and the standard Java runtime includes default implementations for JAXB 2 and XSLT 1. Implementations are pluggable, in case you want additional functionality. Examples are Moxy, a JAXB implementation with some more advanced binding capacities, and Saxon, an implementation of XSLT 2.

You can even combine these technologies. You can unmarshal Java objects using JAXB from an XML file while going through an XSLT transformation, and the other way around: send a Java object through XSLT into XML.